# How to fix a duplicated meta description?

Tags: description

When audit our website in Google webmaster too, I saw duplicate meta descriptions every pages.
I am using: -

```
<?php bloginfo('description'); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

`bloginfo('description')` just displays the site tagline.

> **‘description‘** – Displays the “Tagline” set in Settings > General. This
>   data is retrieved from the “blogdescription” record in the wp_options
>   table.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/bloginfo/#description

So yes, it will be the same on every page.

WordPress does not add meta descriptions to pages, or have the native capability to do so. You would need to use a plugin. Most SEO plugins have this feature.